# Не могу поменять дату в ngx-bootstrap datepicker после ошибки Invalid date

Tags: angular, angular2, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

Решил использовать [ngx-bootstrap datepicker](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/datepicker?tab=examples) в своем Angular проекте.
Все подключилось, все работает кроме одного момента.
Если мы вручную вводим в input некорректную дату, то в значение input-а нам прилетает "Invalid Date". После этого не получается выбрать дату с помощью клика по календарю, пока я не сотру руками текст "Invalid Date".
В [официальных примерах](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/datepicker?tab=examples) все работает нормально.

Пожалуйста, помогите(

Я использую Angular 12 И ngx-bootstrap 7.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было просто поднять версию ngx-bootstrap...

```
"bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^8.0.0"
```

Теперь все работает